# ng-show and ng-hide fails in html5/js chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm confused about the behavior of ng-hide and ng-show in my chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zombiereport/nmojhgiclaimobhpljphbfgmabfmncin

when i put it on the web it's work good : http://1ffa3ba638.url-de-test.ws/zombieReport/partials/popup.html

In the form, ng-show et ng-hide are automatically visible by default (in extension).

Comment: which part exactly uses ng-show and hide?

Comment: like the success and errors messages successMailZR / errorMailZR

Comment: i manually put false to default, but in the extension, i see the messages

Comment: nobody for an answer :( ?

Comment: @FacePalm: You are using a wrong tag for Chrome Apps and your [tag:angularjs-ng-show] is probably not a good one (only 4 questions, too specific)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this same problem. Make sure you include the `angular-csp.css` file in your extensions `index.html` file. You can [download it here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular-csp.css). Also make sure to use the `ng-csp` directive on the `html` tag.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thks ! i only need ths csp css file, and it's works :)

Comment: Yes, that helped.More info from AngularJS docs :
"CSP forbids JavaScript to inline stylesheet rules. In non CSP mode Angular automatically includes some CSS rules (e.g. ngCloak). To make those directives work in CSP mode, include the angular-csp.css manually."